# InternalError due to RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader on WS Deployment

Tags: java, weblogic, jax-ws

Web service ran fine inside Eclipse / WebLogic, but when the ear was built via the build script and the ear was deployed on a standalone WebLogic instance the following error appeared.  Why does this error appear in the different environment?

```
[HTTP:101216]Servlet: "MyServiceServlethttp" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "MyApp-WS". java.lang.InternalError
 at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getClassValue(RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.java:139) 
 at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getClassValue(RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.java:53) 
 at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.PropertyInfoImpl.isApplicable(PropertyInfoImpl.java:212) 
 at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.PropertyInfoImpl.getApplicableAdapter(PropertyInfoImpl.java:223)
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Removing** the following date/dateTime converter from the XSD (and defaulting to XMLGregorianCalendar instead) fixed the error.  Granted I would still like to use a Calendar instead of XMLGregorianCalendar, but I've wasted enough time on this already.

```
<xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
        <jaxb:globalBindings>
            <jaxb:serializable uid="1"/>
            <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Calendar" xmlType="xs:dateTime" parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime" printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDateTime" />
            <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Calendar" xmlType="xs:date" parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDate" printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDate" />
        </jaxb:globalBindings>
    </xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
```

Answer (score 0):

On a similar issue, going in debug and looking at where the exception was thrown was very instructive : a lot of relevant information on the root cause is there, but not provided to the InternalError, making the logging quite useless